# Why Pdf Parser does not work correctly with Cyrillic letters

Tags: php, parsing, pdf

I downloaded and tried to use [PdfParser](https://github.com/smalot/pdfparser) for parsing a pdf file with Cyrillic text. He separates with a space of letters from the very words and lost meaning of words. With the English text, everything works fine, but such problems arise with the Cyrillic script. Help me what should I do to correct such errors when extracting text?
Examples of errors:

Words on the pdf file:

Дар замони ***ҳозира***, мо ***шоҳиди*** ***татбиқи*** васеи ***технологияҳои*** ***иттилоотӣ*** дар ҳаёти ҷомеаи муосир мебошем. Агар, дар ***солҳои*** аввали пайдоиш ***технологияҳои*** компютерӣ асосан барои иҷроиши ҳисобкуниҳои мураккаби илмӣ истифода шуда бошанд, ҳоло компютерҳо, дар корҳои зерин  нигоҳдорӣ, коркард ва пешкаш намудани иттилоот ба намуди зарурӣ, вазифаи асосиро иҷро менамоянд.

After extraction from the pdf file:

Дар  замони  **ҳ    озира** ,   мо      **шо    ҳиди**      **татби қи**    васеи       **технологияҳ   ои**
**иттилоот  ӣ** дар  ҳаёти   ҷомеаи  муосир  мебошем    . Агар  , дар    **сол  ҳои**    аввали
пайдоиш     **технология    ҳои**       компютер    ӣ   асосан      барои       иҷроиши
ҳисобкуни   ҳои     мураккаби       илм ӣ   истифода        шуда        бошанд  ,  ҳ    оло
компютер    ҳо, дар  кор    ҳои  зерин    ниго  ҳдор    ӣ, коркард   ва  пешкаш  намудани
иттилоот ба намуди зарурӣ,  вазифаи  асосиро     иҷро    менамоянд  .

Comment: problem can be related font. Could you change font family if possible?

Comment: @Punit Patel I just changed the font to Calibri but it did not work.

Comment: Did you make `$unicode = true`?

Comment: I through the Microsoft Word program made the font of the Calibri file and saved it as pdf and tried to extract it. And what do you mean about changing the font?

Comment: Now I set mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8") but result incorret.

Comment: Could you upload file here?

Comment: You can download my file from [here](https://mahorat.org/naksha.pdf). I parse this file.

Comment: I will check and let you know

Comment: Ok, Thanks @Punit Patel